# Duda sobre form e input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Es posible enviar desde un index.html, un solo `input` de tipo submit, un `form` (formulario) hacia dos paginas PHP diferentes?
(Un botón que envía la misma información a dos páginas PHP)
De ser así, ¿cómo se debe hacer?

Código html:

```
<form name="buscar" action="valor.php" action="buscar2.php" method="POST" id="myform">
    <div class="block1">
    <label>Selecciona Nombre</label>
    <br>
    <select id="caja1" name="caja1"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="block2">
    <label>Selecciona Valor</label>
    <br>
    <select id="caja2" name="caja2"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="block3">
    <input type="submit" name="Mostrar" value="Mostrar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Creo que necesitas ampliar un poco lo que deseas lograr, además si has intentado algo por favor añade el código a la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Quiero enviar un mismo formulario a dos paginas PHP diferentes.

Comment: ¿Por qué enviar a dos páginas? Por favor edita la pregunta, agrega código del formulario y de lo que quieres hacer en cada página para ver si podemos ayudarte.

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a lo que quieres hacer. Puedes lanzar la acción única y en PHP incluir los archivos que quieras. Si lo que deseas es acciones distintas puedes poner dos botones en el formulario y llamar cada archivo según el botón presionado. Para llamar dos PHP desde el mismo input la única forma es incluyendo uno en otro (a nivel de PHP).

Comment: Es porque quiero que al usar el submit, me lleve a una nueva pagina, pero los datos de tipo POST los pase a otra.

Comment: Precisamente, los datos del `$_POST` serían recuperarlos en el archivo que llamas cuando el formulario es enviado y desde ese archivo puedes pasarlos al otro archivo. La encadenación de archivos tiene que hacerse desde PHP, no desde Javascript, porque el formulario postea a un solo archivo a la vez. Si lo piensas, no tiene sentido querer postear a dos archivos al mismo tiempo. Usando Ajax podrías postear a dos archivos, pero no tiene ningún sentido.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnEnviar").click(function(event) {
    /*Evita que se recargue la página*/
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Serializamos en una sola variable ambos formularios*/
    var allData = $("#formA, #formB").serialize();
    /*Prueba*/
    console.log(allData);
    /*Podemos usar allData para enviarlo por Ajax o lo que sea*/
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>primer formulario</h1>
<form id="formA" action="#" method="POST">
  <label for="Nombre"></label>
  <input type="text" id="NombreA" name="NameA" placeholder="Escriba su nombre">
  <label for="Peso"></label>
  <input type="text" id="PesoA" name="PesoA" placeholder="Peso">
</form>


<h1>Segundo Formulario</h1>
<form id="formB" action="#" method="POST">
  <label for="Nombre"></label>
  <input type="text" id="NombreB" name="NameB" placeholder="Nombre">
  <label for="Nombre"></label>
  <input type="text" id="PesoB" name="PesoB" placeholder="Escriba su correo">
</form>

<button class="Send" id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Y si fuera un mismo formulario a dos paginas?

Comment: usando ajax envias los datos a las dos paginas

Comment: Pero el formulario esta en HTML

Comment: @AlbertoJulioArceEscolar Creo que te adelantaste un poco, el OP según entiendo necesita enviar un mismo formulario a 2 paginas diferentes. Lee [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tu respuesta. Saludos